# QLPreviewController and UTF8 characters

Tags: iphone, ios, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an iPhone app that saves text files with UTF8 characters (umlauts, etc).  If I then view the file with the QLPreviewController, the UTF8 characters are not displayed correctly.  If I view the same file with other apps (Evernote, for example), or copy them to the desktop and view them with textedit, they appear correct.

Is anyone aware of a problem or a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem and found that `QLPreviewController` only seems to display UTF16-encoded text correctly. So I re-encoded my text file before presenting it:

```
NSString* text = ... // Load UTF8-encoded text

NSError* error = nil;

if( [text writeToURL:localFileURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding error:&error] )
{
    // Continue presenting the QLPreviewController from localFileURL
}
else
{
    NSLog( @"An error occured: %@", error );
}
```

Tested on iOS 6.0.1.